# Can always or Always can

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverbs

I am struggling with the order of "can" and "always" in those two sentences:

> One way to illustrate this problem is by imagining a finite number of mathematical points and noting that those points **always can** be described by an infinite number of mathematical functions. In analogy it seems possible that a finite amount of evidence **always can** be described by an infinite number of scientific theories.

In other contexts I understand that you should write "can always" but here it just sounds wrong to me and I want to write it like above, is this wrong?

Comment: 'Can always' sounds better in both places.

Comment: After the first auxiliary verb (i.e, _can always_ rather than _always can_) is the most common, usual, automatic spot for an adverb that modifies the sentence, the clause, or the verb phrase. _Always can_ is not ungrammatical, but it's unusual and draws attention to itself.

Answer (score 1):

'Always' is an adverb that is usually put just before the main part of the verb rather than before a preceding auxiliary. "I have always eaten eggs for breakfast", "We can always hope for a fine day". I think that your cases are no exception: "always can be described" sounds less natural than "can always be described" and doesn't have a different meaning.

With parts of the verb 'to be', the placing of 'always' is usually after the verb, as in "He is always late", "You are always a good friend." Interestingly, "He always is late," and "You always are a good friend" mean similar things but throw the emphasis on to the verb, and would probably be said when the lateness or the friendship had previously been alluded to.